# Generate an html page in document pdf multipage in django

Tags: django, pdf-generation, dynamically-generated, xhtml2pdf

I have an html page that I want to convert to PDF in several copies but in the same document. But when I do this it's the last line of my file that generate then I wanted to have a PDF document so the number of pages is the size of my database.

Answer (score 1):

I was have the same problem 2 months ago .. and after trying several libraries to handle this after all i realized that chrome browser is best tool to convert html to pdf >> so i made

1 - special view to return the original html.

2 - use chrome from cli to convert this page to pdf and save it like :

`os.system( f'chromium --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=<location to save>.pdf --no-margins <your_view_url>')`

3 - then go to this place and return it as normal file.